# How to perform image cropping only by using jquery and display that image in a div at another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

I have browse and uploaded an image by using the below code.Now i need to crop the particular section from that image and have it display that cropped region in a div in another html page. Refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramapriya/f9eSx/1/)

Html:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image" />
<img id="img" />
```

Jquery:

```
 document.getElementById("image").addEventListener('change',function(e){
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        alert(url);
        document.getElementById("img").src = url;
    },false);
```

Comment: Are you uploading to a server if not you cant do it as its considered a security breach. You may be able to see the file pathname and directory path but the html input usually cuts that off and only adds the filename and extension.

Comment: Yes i need to upload it to a server